# Customizing module, model,form,filter path in symfony 1.2

Tags: symfony1, path, customization

We are using symfony in a large project where hundreds of symfony modules, models,fomrs and filters will be created. But keeping all the modules, models, fomrs in their repective folder structure is very difficult to maintain; i.e keeping 300 modules in APP_DIR/modules/ is not suitable. I want to categorise those, for example, i want to put only 5 top level folders under modules/ dir. and keep symfony modules into those folders; and same for form/model/filter.

Can you please suggest any way of doing this?

Thanks,
Shafiul

Comment: Hundreds of modules - you'd probably better separate them into different applications.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you create your modules as plugins.. so you could have 5 plugins with different modules in it. also the lib schema and so on would be placed in the different folders then...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Creating plugin requires some additional tasks. If I could apply the package like concept in java, that was great. Is there any way I can group the model/form/fitlers/modules into packages and the application will get them smoothly at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

To change the libraries for models, fomrs, and filters, create your folders in your lib/ directory and create autoload.yml  in  config/ directory  containing the following:

```
#config/autoload.yml
autoload:
  my_classes:
    name: my_classes
    path: %SF_LIB_DIR%/myLib
    recursive: true
```

The sub-folders will also get autoloaded as long as you keep  `recursive: true`

You cannot change the directory structure of your modules. You can however change the default modules location of each of your symfony application by adding this line to the setup() method of the ProjectConfiguration class to override the sf_app_template_dir settings:
 apps/XXX/config/XXXConfiguration.class.php

```
sfConfig::set('sf_app_module_dir', sfConfig::get('sf_app_dir').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'myModules');
```